# Return emails from Deleted Items back to their original folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Someone I know went into the Large Emails "folder" and cleared it out thinking that those were just duplicates. She didn't realize that she was actually deleting the emails from her many folders.

Now, all the emails are in her Deleted Items folder. Since they came from several different folders, reorganizing them back to those folders is going to be a major task.

Is there any way in Outlook 2010 to select all the emails at once and tell it to move them back to the folders they were orginally in?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Exchange account, you can use the `Folder Tab > Clean Up > Recover Deleted Items` to recover deleted items.

[image]

Note:

> An Exchange account is required for this command to appear.

Detailed instructions are here - [Recover deleted items](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/recover-deleted-items-HA010355039.aspx).

If it's not an Exchange account, the only option is to manually recover each item. Lesson learned the hard way.